# Is there any numerical-accurracy difference on calculating sin(pi/2-A) and cos(A) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, precision, trigonometry, latitude-longitude, numerical-methods

I am reading a matlab function for calculating great circle distance written by my senior collegue.
The distance between two points on the earth surface should be calculated using this formula:

```
d = r * arccos[(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2)) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(long2 – long1)]
```

However, the script has the code like this:

```
dist = (acos(cos(pi/180*(90-lat2)).*cos(pi/180*(90-lat1))+sin(pi/180*(90-lat2)).*sin(pi/180*(90-lat1)).*cos(pi/180*(diff_long)))) .* r_local;
(-180 < long1,long2 <= 180, -90 < lat1,lat2 <= 90)
```

Why are `sin(pi/2-A)` and `cos(pi/2-A)` used to replace `cos(A)` and `sin(A)`？
Doesn't it introduced more error source by using the constant `pi`?
Since `lat1`, `lat2` might be very close to zero in my work, is this a trick on the numerical accuracy of MATLAB's `sin()` and `cos()` function?

Look forward to answers that explain how trigonometric functions in MATLAB work and analyze the error of these functions when the argument is close or equal to 0 and pi/2.

Comment: The error deriving from assuming the Earth is a perfect sphere is probably larger than the one due to any fancy manipulation of the trigonometric functions...

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt this has to do with accuracy. Or at least, I don't think this helps any when it comes to accuracy.

The maximum difference between both `sin(pi/2-A) - cos(A)` and `cos(pi/2-A) - sin(A)` is `1.1102e-16`, which is very small. This is just basic floating point accuracy, and there's really no way of telling which of the numbers is more correct. Note that `cos(pi/2) = 6.1232e-17`. So, if `theta = 0`, your colleague's code `cos(pi/2-0)` will give an error of `6.1232e-17`, while simply doing the obvious `sin(0)` will be correct.

If you need numbers that are more accurate than this then you can try `vpa`.

I guess this is either because your colleague found another formula and implemented that, or he/she's confused and has attempted to increase the accuracy.

The latter might be the case if he/she tried to avoid the approximations `sin(theta) ≈ theta` and `cos(theta) ≈ 1` for small values of `theta`. However, this doesn't make sense, since `cos(pi/2-theta) ≈ theta` and `sin(pi/2-theta) ≈ 1` for small values of `theta`.

Comment: I agree, this looks like a complication that doesn't improve results.

Comment: I'd also point out that converting from ```rad``` to ```deg``` and viceversa should be done using the dedicated functions ```rad2deg``` and ```deg2rad```, instead of using factors involving ```pi```. I suspect the code was written for an old version of MATLAB, when those conversion function were still part of a toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose is to increase accuracy, this seems a very poor idea. When the angle is small, 90-A spoils any accuracy. That even makes tiny angles vanish (90-ε=90).

On the opposite, the sine of tiny angles is very close to the angle itself (radians) and for this reason quite accurately computed, while the cosine is virtually 1 or 1-A²/2. For top accuracy on tiny angles, you may resort to the versine, using versin(A):= 1-cos(A) = 2 sin²(A/2) and rework the equations in terms of 1-versin(A) instead of cos(A).

If the angle is close to 90°, accuracy is lost anyway, 90°-A will not restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Best chance is to ask directly to the author of the text where you got those expressions from, if possible indeed.

It may be the case that the original expressions come from navigation formulae that were written when calculations were done manually: pencil paper ruler, no computers, no calculators.

Tables and graphs were then used to speed up results: `pi-x` was equivalent to **start read table from other side** or read **graph upside-down**.